# Disable slider control when certain value exceed Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, slider, windows-phone-8

I have a slider control which resize a bitmap. When the bitmap size exceeds the screen width, I want to disallow further valuechanged but, decreasing the value is allowed.

So far I set the slider to IsEnabled property to false essentially disable the slider when the bitmap size exceed the screen width. But how do I renabled it again when user only slide the thumb to the left (decreasing the value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better handling the limits inside of `ValueChanged`, rather than disabling the control to avoid the problem you are seeing.

Or even better, as you know the dimensions of your original bitmap you can calculate the maximum allowed value of the slider. You can set that at run time and that then might allow you to side step this completely.

Comment: I tried you suggestion by setting a flag when the maximum allowed value of the slider is reached and set this value to `sliderSize.Maximum = currentCharObject.MaxSliderValue` inside of `ValueChanged`

Strangely after that, ValueChanged event no longer fired.

Comment: You need to separate those two out. Changing `sliderSize.Maximum` inside `ValueChanged` seems like a bad idea.